# Listening on UDP socket

Tags: java, sockets, udp, listen

I am using this code to receive data from a UDP socket and return it as string:

```
byte[] receiveData = new byte[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket);
return new String(receivedPacket.getData(), 0, receivedPacket.getLength());
```

I set MAX_PACKET_SIZE to 1024 which causes Java to reserve a 1024bit long byte[] everytime a packet arrives. This causes a *lot* of overhead if the packet is much smaller than 1024 byte.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Maybe with some kind of while() read cycle? I am not very familiar with Java yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the packet if you want to avoid the overhead of creating mutliple arrays (although short-lived objects actually have very little impact on performance anyway).

Note that you can't read a UDP datagram in chunks, as anything beyond the end of the DatagramPacket you pass to [receive](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)) is discarded.

Edit - I checked, and [DatagramChannel.receive](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#receive(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) is pretty much the same. You really do need to ensure that your buffer is big enough to receive the largest possible valid datagram.